# How to make CSS Grid with content sized cells?

Tags: css, grid, cell

I am new to coding, still learning from online resources.

For website I am working on, I need to make four columns of "reviewers' quotes".
I am using a CSS Grid to work on and its working beautifully.
Except, all cells in the grid are equal height. Some quotes are shorter than others, leaving unsightly gaps. *(there are many quotes and I am using four columns on desktop view)*. I want to make cells adjust height to size of content inside them.

How can I fix this? I am sure there is something very simple I am missing on. I am using this format:

```
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item">Quote01</div>
      <div class="grid-item">Quote02</div>
      <div class="grid-item">Quote03</div>
      <div class="grid-item">Quote04</div>
      <div class="grid-item">Quote05</div>
      <div class="grid-item">Quote06</div>
      <div class="grid-item">Quote07</div>
      <div class="grid-item">Quote08</div>
      <div class="grid-item">Quote09</div>
<div class="grid-item">Quote10</div>
<div class="grid-item">Quote11</div>
<div class="grid-item">Quote12</div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS is like this:

```
.grid-container {
    width: 80%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[image: This is the current clean, well aligned grid]

[image: This is how I want the grid's cell to inherit coontent size in height]

Comment: can you please add screenshot it will help to figure out issue.

Comment: @KararBarcha I quickly created these images in a graphic software. The top image is how the grid is right now. The bottom is how I would like it to behave, where the individual cells change height as per the content inside them.